# PHP: Namespace and calling one class into other

Tags: php, oop

I have two classes, `Class1` and `Class2` which are under namespace `myNameSpace`.

I want to create an instance of `Class2` in class`and I am getting an error in implementing file`Class 'myNameSpace\Class2' not found in.. `. Code given below:

**Class1.php**

```
namespace myNameSpace {

use myNameSpace\Class2;

class Class1
{
    public function myMethod()
    {
        $obj = new Class2();
    }
}
```

**call.php**

```
namespace myNameSpace {
    include 'Class1.php';
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);

    use myNameSpace\Class1;
    $o = new Class1();
    $o->myMethod();
}
```

Comment: I would concur with PHP here... I'm not seeing where you define any `Class2` either...

Answer (score 1):

If they're both in the same namespace you should not have to use a "use" statement. Seems more likely that you're not simply **include**ing both files.

Maybe what you're looking for is autoloading? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Definitely I am looking for autoLoading but how do I do it? I mean, do I have to include file anyway?

Comment: Is there any centralize way to do all includes/loading rather than on multiple files? Something like Java/Python import?